# Why the definition for optimal value is the $\inf{f_0(x)}$ rather than $\min{f_0(x)}$?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Suppose an optimization problem

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{x}{\text{minimize}}
& & f_0(x) \\
& \text{subject to}
& & f_i(x) \leq b_i, \; i = 1, \ldots, m.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Then, the optimal value is defined as

$$p^{\star} = \inf\{f_{0}(x) \: | x \in \mathcal{A} \}$$

where $A$ is the feasible set. My question is that why we use $\inf$ rather than $\min$ for representing the optimal value?

Comment: Are you familiar with the definition of supremum/infimum?

Comment: @Math1000: Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not every set has a minimum value, but every set that’s bounded below has an infimum value. If you used min instead of inf, you would lose the ability to talk about many functions

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, the minimum isn't always attainable in the feasible set. In this case you need to look for the infimum.

However, in the context of the problem statement, if $f$ is also a continuous function and $A$ (the obtainable set) is compact, then the minimum and infimum are the same and you can attain the infimum in the attainable set.

Comment: Consider the example $f(x)=e^{x}$ on $R$.  This is a continuous function, and the inf is 0, but the minimum is never attained.  Also, consider $f(x)=x^{2}$ $R^{++}=\left\{ x | x > 0 \right\}$.  Again, the inf is 0, but the minimum is not attained.  It's true that if $f$ is a continuous function on a closed and bounded set, then the minimum is attained.

Comment: I forgot to add that the attainable set is compact, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way to understand this is to take a look at the wiki link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum, starting from "The concepts of infimum and supremum are similar to minimum and maximum, but are more useful in analysis because they better characterize special sets which may have no minimum or maximum."